# How long does it take a return the TxHash for a transaction in the MainNet?

Tags: transactions

I have been doing some work on the private ETH node and when I submit a transaction the local ETH node returns a TxHash immediately. My currently implementation completely relies on the immediate TxHash that returned to me.

Is this behavior same in the Ethereum Mainnet? Or the TxHash is returned only after the message is broadcasted to the whole Ethereum network? Will there be a delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction hash does not depend on the transaction being broadcasted, after it is signed it should be immediately available.